# .NET Query With list inside can not translate

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core-3.1

I am having trouble doing a query which involves a list of ENUMS inside a query, I remember doing similar query like this in .NET 2.2 and don't remember having troubles with it. So this is my query currently:

```
        string[] motivosCompra = dadosConsultoria.MotivosCompra.Split(",");
        List<TipoCor> tonsFavoritos = _colorsService.ConverterFromListString(dadosConsultoria.CoresFavoritas.Split(","));

        return _context.Produtos
            .Include(c => c.Cor)                
            .Include(d => d.DadoEmpresa)               
            .Include(i => i.Imagens)               
            .Include(p => p.Peca)               
            .Include(e => e.EstilosProduto)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.EstiloProduto)
            .Include(c => c.Categorias)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Categoria)
            .Where(p => p.Ativo                    
                && p.DadoEmpresa.Id == IdEmpresa
                && p.Peca.Id == tipoDePeca.Id
                && p.Categorias.Any(c => motivosCompra.Any(m => m == c.Categoria.Nome))
                && p.EstilosProduto.Any(e => e.EstiloProduto.Nome == estiloNome)
                && tonsFavoritos.Any(t => p.Cor.Tom == t) 
                && p.Cor.Temperatura == temperatura)                
            .Take(5)
            .ToList();
```

When I try to do this I get:

> The LINQ expression ... could not be translated.

If I remove this line:

```
&& tonsFavoritos.Any(t => p.Cor.Tom == t)
```

It works fine.

Is there a problem in using an Any for a list inside a query? It seams weird to me, because the other one that I am using seams to work fine, in:

```
&& p.Categorias.Any(c => motivosCompra.Any(m => m == c.Categoria.Nome))
```

EDIT:

The definition of TipoCor:

```
public enum TipoCor
{
    [Display(Name = "Neutras")]
    Neutras = 0,
    [Display(Name = "Terrosas")]
    Terrosas = 1,
    [Display(Name = "Pasteis")]
    Pasteis = 2,
    [Display(Name = "Suaves")]
    Suaves = 3,
    [Display(Name = "Vivas")]
    Vivas = 4,
    [Display(Name = "Escuras")]
    Escuras = 5
}
```

Tom is of TipoCor type.

Comment: Post the definition of `TipoCor` class including its Equals, and also some info about what a `.Tom` is, if it's not a TipoCor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using entity framework or some other orm. Which tries to translate your query into some sql syntax.

And i can see that you are trying to make an equetion  `p.Cor.Tom == t` in this line.
So `Tom` is a complex type. And you cant compare complex types in IQueryable queries. Because simply it doesn't know how to compare your custom class.

Basically what you can do is try to compare the primary or unique id of your classes. Like:

```
tonsFavoritos.Any(t => p.Cor.Tom.Id == t.Id)
```

And also you may need to create a list of primary keys with tonsFavoritos veriable.
Gonna be like:

```
     int[] tonsFavoritos = _colorsService.ConverterFromListString(dadosConsultoria.CoresFavoritas.Split(",")).Select(c=> c.Id).ToArray();

     //and then edit query like below:
     tonsFavoritos.Contains(t => p.Cor.Tom.Id)
```

So with this way the orm tool simply convert this query to something like

```
select * from CARS where CAR.Id in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

The reason why your other Any query is working it is because not in memory collection. It's a replica of "Categorias" table. Not really an actual collection in memory.

Comment: so, Tom is an enum, should I try to convert it to an int?

Comment: Yes, whether it is a class or enum. Just try to define it as primitive types. Read again my answer i added some edits